# UserProfile Picture not being updated with AD

Tags: 2013, active-directory, user-profile-property, picture, thumbnail

I have established Picture mapping so it can be feed from AD. However, pictures are not being populated. I followed this article [Adding Pictures to Active Directory and Show in SharePoint 2013](http://blog.blumshapiro.com/blog/2013/05/13/adding-pictures-to-active-directory-and-show-in-sharepoint-2013/)just to confirm my setup is proper and made sure everything is exact. see setup below

[image]

After this setting it looked like below.
[image]

FIM status : still missing thumbnailphoto attribute
[image]

Comment: two thing, did you run full sync and Update-SPProfilePhotoStore  powershell commnad?

Comment: Yes sir. First I ran Full Sync yesterday and then update-spprofilephotostore this morning. I am using "SharePoint Active Directory Import" for Synchronization Settings (which is really faster than SP Profile Sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh You are using the Active Directory Import. You are out of luck. ADI import does not support the complex property import. Profile Picture fall under the Complex property so it does not supported.

We had the same issue and we switched to UPS after couple of months troubleshooting with MSFT support.

Comment: 1. I changed the sync connection option to SP profile synce, Ran a full sync but thumbnailphoto does not get picked up by FIM. http://i.stack.imgur.com/JDqL1.png

Comment: Waqas: do you think you upload few screen shots so i can make sure my setups are correct.

Comment: did you recreate the UPA and then configure sync, map the property, full sync, update script.? are you seeing the profile picture in the Mysite folder?

Comment: did all of that except recreating upa which is pain in the rare.

Comment: I deleted the old connection. Re-created sync connection and made sure connection type is sp profile sync. re-map picture with thumbnailphoto, full sync, ran the powershell script and now they are populated.

Comment: awesome! happy live after

Answer (score 0):

The AD import option does not automatically synchronize photos from Active Directory to SharePoint Server 2013. If you need to import photos you must use profile synchronization. For more information, see 
[Microsoft technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219646.aspx)

After starting UPSS, Do iisreset. then start full profile sync. Hope this helps.

Comment: on All SharePoint servers (apps, wfe, etc)

Comment: The AD import option does not automatically synchronize photos from Active Directory to SharePoint Server 2013. If you need to import photos you must use profile synchronization. For more information, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219646.aspx

Comment: After starting the service, do iisreset (on server running UPS). And then start full profile sync.